# How i can filter ListView items ?

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, searchview

I'm trying to filter `ListView` items with `SearchView`.

this is my XML code. :

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        style="@style/CodeFont">

        </ListView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/list" />

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:hint="Search contact.."
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@android:id/list"

        />
```

and this is my java code

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String poiName = ((TextView)(view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))).getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Message.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",poiName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        startManagingCursor(Cursor);
        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int [] to ={android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

        final SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,Cursor,from,to);
        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        list=getListView();
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
```

The `ListView` is displaying all the contacts in the user phone.
I want to make a filter with the `SearchView`

Comment: Just take the data from your `SearchView` and modify your `getContentResolver().query()` call accordingly (there's a bunch of `null` parameters which you can use).

Comment: @SqueezyMo Can you explain me more specifically ? i didn't fully understand the getContentResolver().query() method

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html). You can effectively restrict the returned rows with a `SELECT` statement passed in as a third parameter. You can see available columns [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to retrieve all numbers that contain whatever you have entered into your `SearchView` and show them in ascending order. This can be achieved with something like this:

```
    String query = searchView.getQuery().toString();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            TextUtils.isEmpty(query) ? null : ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?",
            TextUtils.isEmpty(query) ? null : new String[] {query},
            TextUtils.isEmpty(query) ? null : ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " ASC"
    );
```

Do not forget to notify your adapter whenever you change text in your `SearchView`.